# Trying to get Checkbox to write values onto Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get excel to write values onto a spreadsheet when a checkbox is selected.

The name for each checkbox is Dog, Cat, and Other

Any combination of the checkbox can be selected (the user can select all that applies), and I want the choice the user chooses to be written on the "Animals" sheet onto excel, starting at cell B10.

My problem is that I am having trouble linking the users choice onto the excel spreadsheet and once the user clicks the 'OK' button, the form does not close. I have copied my code here along with a screenshot of the module.

```
Sub Source()
Call OK_Click
End Sub

 Sub OK_Click()
    If Dog.Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Animals").Range("B10").Value = Dog
    ElseIf Catl.Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Animals").Range("B11").Value = Cat
    ElseIf Other.Value = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Animals").Range("B12").Value = Other
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try `=Dog.Name` etc., or `=`the string `"Dog"`, etc. I also think you don't need the `Else` clauses.Just use an `If Then` statement n separate lines for each checkbox.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Animals").Range("B10").Value = IIf(Dog.Value,"Dog", "")`